# How to align Vec<f32> along 128-bit, 256-bit, 512-bit boundaries?

Tags: rust

To use intrinics like [`_mm_load_ps`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/core/arch/x86_64/fn._mm_load_ps.html) and [`_mm256_load_ps`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/core/arch/x86_64/fn._mm256_load_ps.html), I need to allocate *dynamically* sized `Vec<f32>` and `Vec<f64>` such that the data is aligned along 128-bit, 256-bit and 512-bit boundaries. How can this be done?

Comment: [`std::alloc::alloc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/alloc/fn.alloc.html)

Comment: [`align_to`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.align_to) is useful for this purpose, if you don't align it to start with.

Comment: You can also just use `Vec<__m256>` to start with, and cast to a slice of `f64s` or whatever.

Comment: @PitaJ I like your last idea. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe `Vec` allows you to control the inner allocation alignment.  However, there are functions that allow you to take a slice and get three slices back: a (possibly empty) unaligned prefix, a middle aligned piece, and a final (possibly empty) unaligned suffix.  These are `slice::align_to` and the nightly-only `slice::as_simd` and their respective `_mut` variants.

This will allow you to process the beginning and end elements separately in a non-SIMD approach and then do the rest of the data with SIMD.  This is the approach you'd have to take anyway for a general slice from an external source.